# Select code block in vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Given a code like this:

```
588          while ($linecounter > 0) {
589             $token = " ";
590             while ($token != PHP_EOL) {
591                 if (fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
592                     $beginning = true;
593                     break;
594                 }
595                 $token = fgetc($handle);
596                 $pos--;
597             }
598             $linecounter--;
599             if ($beginning) {
600                 rewind($handle);
601             }
602         }
```

The cursor is at the character `=` in the line 590.

Which is the most efficient way to select the code block:

1. lines 590-597
2. lines 591-596 (just the inner part)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To do the first:

- Hit `$` to go to the end of the lineover the `{`
- Push `v` or `V` (depending on whether you want to select lines or not)
- Push `%` (to jump to the matching bracket).

To select just the inner part, go inside the inner part and use the `i{` directional modifier.

For example, to delete everything inside the current `{…}` block, type: `di{`.

Comment: Wow, I have just learned how to use `yi(`, thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

1. `$` to jump to the end of the line you're on (to be over the opening brace)
   `v` to begin a selection (`V` for whole lines)
   `%` to jump to the matching brace.
2. `j` to go down one line so your cursor is inside the braces you are trying to select
   `v` to begin a selection (`V` for whole lines)
   `i{` select everything inside the braces

Comment: Method 2 is probably the best method here, since the $ movement in method 1 only works because the opening brace is at the end of the line. Method 2 works without the j movement if your cursor is anywhere within the braces.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Caleb's answer just slightly, `vi{` will select the "inside" of the code block. To include the "outside" of the code block, ie including the braces, use `va{`.

This won't include the `while` stanza though. To do that you can use `o` to move the cursor to the beginning of the selection, and then `0` to move the selection to the beginning of the line.